# Matching an expression in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

How can I match **create new device** and **create device** using Regular Expression in Python?

```
re.search(r'create (new)* device', line, re.I)
```

doesn't seem to do the trick...

Comment: `create (new )?device`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!